# Application in focus with Timer

Tags: vb.net

I have created a application which uses more then 500 clients of mine.
The thing is that they would like to have a feature to check how many minutes (hours) their workers effectively worked in that application.
So I came to the idea to add a Timer which will count how many minutes my application is working. I guess that Timer should be a background process.
My idea is to make it running in background whenever my application process is working.
Any thoughts about this or any better idea?

Comment: "[...]their workers effectively worked in that application" seems to be difficult to control. Adding a Timer which is counting running time does not mean that the worker is working on it. To be more accurate I would count the time that the application is in the foreground. **EDIT:** Sorry i didn't read "in focus" at your title.

Comment: I thought about counting the time that the application was in Focus (Top).

Comment: Yep. I just realized it

Comment: or even better, when application is in Focus and when Mouse coursor is moving.

Comment: Even more accurate, you can set up checkpoints in your code and go accumulating them as the user is working (passing through procedures). This assures you that the worker is actually using the application

Comment: @equisde well the only idea I have is to make the triggers for all stored procedures (there is more then 1.000 SPs in my application) since there is more then 100 .dll files and 3 .exe with more then 5.000.000 lines of code :)

Comment: Argh! So that could be a struggle :D  Anyway, you can set them up  just in the main procedures or in the procedures which you are sure the user will pass through them. I can think of nothing better.

Comment: You don't need a `Timer`, that wouldn't be accurate, nor do you need anything running in the background.  All you need to do is create a `Stopwatch` object.  Start it when the application is in focus and stop it whenever it goes out of focus.  At any time, you can query it for the current running total.

Comment: Thanks @StevenDoggart I will take a look about that...